# CSS styling links in bootstrap 3

Tags: css

I've got a problem with my menu - when I added "nav" class to my links, hover of the whole element is permanently white - I can't change it. When i delete nav, then I can style it easily.

Any ideas?

```
  <body id="home"  ng-controller="IndexController"> 
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" ng-click="change('main')" href="#">Main Page</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li ng-click="checkIt()"><a href="#">Stuff 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stuff 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stuff 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stuff 4</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Registration</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Log in</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

and my CSS:

```
$bg-color: #333;
    $font-color: #fff;
    $primary-color: #008ed6;
    $dark-overlay: rgba(21, 21, 21, 0.8);
    $icon-size: 30px;

    body{
        background-color: $bg-color;
        color: $font-color;
    }

    .container{
        padding: 8px;
    }

    .navbar{
        border-bottom: $primary-color 3px solid;
        opacity: 0.8;
        background-color: $dark-overlay;
        font-color: white;
    }

    #home{
        min-height:700px;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        .fa{
            color:$primary-color;
            background: #fff;
            padding: 4px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-size: $icon-size; 
        }

    }

    .navbar-brand{
        color: white;
        :hover{
        color: darken(white, 15%);
        }
    }


    a{
        color: white;
    }

    a:hover {
        color: darken(white, 15%);
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

I had to style a too, because default color for font was blue. When I added nav class to my navbar-header it is working properly.

@edit - look at this screen (I described it in comment)

[image]

Comment: `added "nav" class to my links` You're trying to add a class of **NAV** to the **LINKS** ? Look at Bootstraps default menu code. A class of 'nav' doesn't belong on the links... that is your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to access the rule from parent > child > child > child to change css rule or you can use !important after css rule.
That's it.

Comment: Instead of just describing what to do, which should be a comment, you should give a working example of what to do for it to be an answer.

Comment: For example I added to my css style: .nav:hover !important rule with bg-color: green. Then, when I run over my 1st item - hover is still white, but the rest is green. Screen in my post